# What is everything involved from typing in code to executing a program?

Tags: ide, compiler-construction

I realized, when just asking a question, I don't understand all the components that are part of the coding process.

This seems a silly question, but I can't find a definitive answer on Google, Wiki, nothing.

What exactly are all the parts called, and how do they work and intertwine? I'm talking whatever you type code into, whatever checks that for errors, compiles it, and runs it.

I'd appreciate any links, repeats, etc. I apologize for such a bland, stupid question.

EDIT: Well, I'm trying to start Perl, so anything about Perl would help. Like, how to use Notepad++ and eventually compile Perl.

Comment: Do you have a particular language in mind?  The answers are somewhat different for different languages.

Comment: Not a stupid question, just a day 1 question.

Comment: Good luck and dont be afraid to ask more questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write code
2. Run code in one of two ways[*]

   1. Compiled languages (C, C++, D, Java, C#)

      1. Compile the code into an executable file with the *compiler* tool.
      2. Run the executable
   2. Interpreted languages (Perl Python Ruby Lua Haskell Lisp & more)

      1. Run the code in an interpreter, e.g., `perl foo.pl`
3. Debug code.

edit: Since the question was refined to be the Perl development cycle...

You will need an editor and a 'shell', which is used to command the system with. In particular, you want a 'command-line interface'. On Windows, you start this with running cmd.exe on the Run dialog (Windows + R is the shortcut).

You see a strange black and white box with a blinking cursor, reminding you of ancient systems redolent of gurus and wizards. You panic and refer to Google, getting a [web page](http://commandwindows.com/). Finding the command to change directory and list files is recommended...

Upon arriving at the directory where you stored your Perl file, you issue the command `perl myfilename.pl`, where `myfile.pl` is the file you saved. As is common for programming, you find some errors that appear to be incomprehensible, and you refer to Stackoverflow.com once again...

* I have elided, glossed, and moved past many of the details, as this is an introductory question. A full discussion is known as "senior-level course on compilers".

Comment: I wish I could upvote this again, because I just learned AND lawled.
Thanks for the help!